# getContentChildren equivalent in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-2.x

I have a custom element

```
<!-- element template -->
<dom-module id="custom-element">
  <template>
    <style></style>
    <div class="toggle">
      <slot id="toggleContent" name="toggle"></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>...</script>
</dom-module>

<!--usage-->
<custom-element>
  <div slot="toggle">I'm the toggle</div>
</custom-element>
```

In Polymer 1.0, I could get the distributed child node by using

```
[this.getContentChildren('#toggleContent')\[0\];][1]
```

which would return `<div toggle>I'm the toggle</div>`

However in Polymer 2. `getContentChildren` isn't supported anymore and doing it this way

```
this.$.toggleContent.assignedNodes({flatten: true}).filter(function(n) {
  return (n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE);
});
```

doesn't return me the expected element, `<div slot="toggle">I'm the toggle</div>`.

How do I get the equivalent result using `assignedNodes()` in Polymer 2?

Please see following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq7lvk?p=preview)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
this.shadowRoot
  .querySelector('#toggleContent')
  .assignedNodes({flatten:true})
  .filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
```

But if you have single `slot` then you can just do:

```
this.shadowRoot
      .querySelector('slot')
      .assignedNodes({flatten:true})
      .filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
```

> The `this.$` hash is created when the shadow DOM is initialized. Nodes
>   created dynamically are not added to the `this.$` hash. So, you have to use `this.shadowRoot.querySelector`.

**Update** After the demo provided:

`_toggleEl` is an array/object and you are comparing it with an element. So, it is returning `false` always. So, use `var equal = elementClicked === this.toggleEl[0]` like you did in `polymer 1`.

Comment: hmm, no that's not the issue. Would you mind looking at the following plunker? http://plnkr.co/edit/Nq7lvk?p=preview

Comment: Since `this._toggleEl ` is an array, why are you not using  `var equal = elementClicked === this.toggleEl[0]` like you did in `polymer 1`?

Comment: Oh yes! you are right! Thanks for pointing it out. When I looked at the console print, it looked like it returned an object and not an array and therefore i never thought about it. PEBCAK. Would you mind editing your answer and I'll gladly accept it? Thanks!